# How can I change the shading of beamer's \tableofcontents[currentsection]?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, shading

I like to use `\tableofcontents[currentsection]` as an orientation at the start of a new section. But in my experience (depending on the projector), the default shading of the other sections can be to light. How can I change it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\frame{
\frametitle{Title}
A frame of the first section
}

\section{Second Section}

\frame{
\frametitle{The shaded section is too light!}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the `section in toc shaded` template; one way to do so, is to use the second optional argument (default value = `20`) to a higher value (a value of `100` gives no shading at all and the entry will look like the no-shaded ones; a value of zero gives a completely transparent entry):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}[default][50]

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\frame{
\frametitle{Title}
A frame of the first section
}

\section{Second Section}

\frame{
\frametitle{The shaded section is not too light anymore!}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's precisely what I wanted, thanks! Related to the problem is that the background of blocks tends to get too light. Is there a likewise easy solution for this?

Comment: @NauC You're welcome. Regarding the other issue, since it is not directly related to the subject of this question, I think it's better if you open a fresh new question.

Comment: @NauC don't forget to add to your follow-up question the `beamer`theme(s) that you are using.

Comment: – Thanks for the tip, but I figured out how to do it on my own :)